# post on timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

We have requirement in our FB App to post some content on user wall, this activity is performed by FB app admin (publisher) who select the content and post to list of user on there wall.
Problem statement:We have used feed dialoge before february 2013 changes to post on user wall which was also coming on time line.Now we are unable to post on timeline.
Please find my code snippet before february 2013 changes:

```
FB.api('/' + uid[i] + '/feed', 'post',  parameter)
```

After the changes of February 2013 in we used updated feed dialogue api due and after that we are unable to post on user timeline, it is coming as news feed.
Please find our new code snippet:

```
var obj = {method: 'feed', to: '<%#fbid %>',  message: aMessage}
```

We looked into facebook developer forum and googled to other development blog’s but couldn’t find any effective and working solution.

We have few queries and will be good for us if you can provide the clarity on that which will help to meet our client requirement.

Query1: Can we post on user timeline using any FB api (by admin who is not added any user in his friend list)?
Query2: Does feed dialog allow us to post on user timeline, if yes then please share code snippet (technology stack: asp.net)?
Query3: Does facebook have any api to send notification?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No Anvesh, It's working fine and posting on Newsfeed, but client expectation is that post should come on timeline.apart of this they want to notify user when there post is published on there wall.I am unable to post on timeline neither I am able to send notification to all App user.

Comment: Any help will appreciated....

Comment: Sorry for delay, please check answer and reply if you need any clarification

Comment: Use [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) with the `to` parameter. The notification will be sent to the receiver automatically after the post is published.

Comment: Hi...As you can see my code snippet,I am already using "To", but that is not sending notification even after post is published.I was able to see notification till 6th Feb 2013,after that it is not showing notification.Let me know if you have some alternatives.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all 'admin' or anyone who is not friend of a user can't post anything to User's timeline.
If your admin is friend of the User then you can use "stream.share" to post on the User's wall using Facebook JavaScript SDK as

```
<script>
 var share = {
    method: 'stream.share',
    u: 'http://www.fbrell.com/'
 };

 FB.ui(share, function(){
       //Call back function
 });
</script>
```

Or you can still use [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) and ask admin to tag people on the post.

You can use extended access token to post to the User's wall as if User himself posted the content, although I wouldn't suggest you to use it to communicate with user as it might be on the grey are of Facebook's policy to communicate with user. And if it is for non-User communication message then do make sure your User knows that this behavior is expected. 
You can utilize [Notification API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/) to communicate with your user or to re-engage with him.